How to incorporate Catch2 into a C++Builder program?
I've downloaded Catch2 (V3) from the GetIt package manager in C++Builder 12.1. How do I use it with a program? What do I need to do to make Catch2 test statements in a program be recognized?

Did you read its documentation? See the readme at https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2 and the docs at  https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/tree/devel/docs
